# Sound buttons don't work

Tags: debian, debian-jessie, openbox

I install Debian 8 Jessie minimum on my Dell laptop with LXQT. I try to set actions on my sound buttons, but actions don't work... I edit `~/.config/openbox/lxqt-rc.xml` for both user and root with the following actions (in block `<keyboard>`):

```
  <!-- AUDIO BUTTONS -->
  <keybind key="XF86AudioLowerVolume">
      <action name="Execute">
        <startupnotify>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
          <name>volumedown</name>
        </startupnotify>
        <command>amixer -c 0 set Master 5%- unmute</command>
      </action>
  </keybind>

  <keybind key="XF86AudioRaiseVolume">
      <action name="Execute">
        <startupnotify>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
          <name>volumeup</name>
        </startupnotify>
        <command>amixer -c 0 set Master 5%+ unmute</command>
      </action>
  </keybind>

  <keybind key="XF86AudioMute">
      <action name="Execute">
        <startupnotify>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
          <name>volumedown</name>
        </startupnotify>
        <command>amixer -c 0 set Master toggle</command>
      </action>
   </keybind>
```

After reboot sound power doesn't change, when pressing the buttons. I open `xev` for see button detection and all was good. This is output when I press button for mute volume:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
    root 0xd6, subw 0x0, time 569224, (-96,387), root:(999,666),
    state 0x0, keycode 121 (keysym 0x1008ff12, XF86AudioMute), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
    root 0xd6, subw 0x0, time 569363, (-96,387), root:(999,666),
    state 0x0, keycode 121 (keysym 0x1008ff12, XF86AudioMute), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

When I write in console command `amixer -c 0 set Master toggle` - all sound mutes.

---

Why won't the sound buttons work and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in window manager. Default was `xfwm4` instead if `openbox`. When I change it on `openbox` windows manager - all work fine.

---

For see your window manager open: *menu > preferences > lxqt settings > session setings*

You can enable `openbox` window manager by installing open box and enabling it in session settings.

```
sudo apt-get install openbox
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gsettings reset volume-up
gsettings reset volume-down
gsettings reset volume-mute
```

execute them in terminal
and add pulse audio plugin to your panel.
it worked for me on Debian stretch